# CKFinder external "browse server" button

Tags: php, file-upload, ckfinder

If I integrate between CKEditor && CKFinder I can put a "browse server" button inside ckeditor.

But what if I want to put a "browse server" button in an external page (NOT ckeditor?)

The following code may explain:

```
<form> <input type="text" name="path_to_file" /> //BROWSE SERVER BUTTON, like file-upload.
```

Just like inside CKEditor, but in an external page. Instead of looking in your computer files look in the server files.

Comment: `The following code explains:`....hardly.

Comment: changed it. Instead of looking in your computer files look in the server files.

Comment: This is a rather complex feature that you'll need to build (or copy from CKFinder if that is allowed and possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the "enhancing html forms" in http://ckfinder.com/demo or "popup" in the samples provided in the package.